# How to process the data in the table, which is frequently inserted

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-deadlocks

I have a table dbo.RawMessage, which allows anther system to frequently(insert 2 records per second) insert data.

I need to process the data in the RawMessage, and put the processed data in dbo.ProcessedMessage.

Because the processing logic is not very complected, so  my approach is add a insert trigger in the RawMessage table, but sometime I got deadlock.

I am using SQL SERVER EXPRESS

My questions:
1.Is this a stuipid approach?
2.If not, how to improve?
3.If yes, please guide me the graceful way

Comment: Generally we try to direct apps/users away from the `INSERT raw-data -> Trigger-processing -> INSERT Processed` approach and towards an approach like `EXEC spProcessing(raw-data) -> INSERT Processed` approach.  Whether that alone would address your deadlocks has a lot to do with whats actually going on in your trigger processing.

Comment: forget to touch the dbo.RawMessage.This part is fixed.

Comment: Can you explain why is there a deadlock? Because I don't think it is obvious!   I understand that when you insert into the dbo.RawMessage table an X-lock is acquired on dbo.RawMessage and, due to the trigger, on the dbo.ProcessedMessage table, but this alone does not justify a deadlock, or does it?